# Android working with GIF files

Tags: java, android, bitmap, gif

I have been trying to implement some code I was given but cant seem to get it functioning. I have starting off, 2 images, one which is a jpg and can be fetched no promblem, I simply have an ImageView for it.

The next image ends up being a gif with transparency. I need that gone, so a friend helped me with some code to deplete it. But it just does not go away...

I start with my UI thread:

```
    // BMP is a async task used for regular images:
    bmp = new BitmapTask(imageview_topo);
    bmp.execute("http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/Overlays/Topo/Short/ILN_Topo_Short.jpg");

    // decodeBlack is an async class used for getting rid of black transperancy
    // I execute the URL to the asynctask:
    decodeBlack = new BitmapDecodeBlack(imageview_counties); 
    decodeBlack.execute("http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/Overlays/Highways/Short/ILN_Highways_Short.gif");
```

The BitmapDecodeBlack object class:

```
public class BitmapDecodeWhite extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

private ImageView imageview;

public BitmapDecodeWhite(ImageView imageview) {
    this.imageview = imageview;
}
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {

    String urldisplay = url[0];

    //New Bitmap to return:
    Bitmap icon = null;

    //Try to retrieve the icon from the NOAA:
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Return the icon fetched:
    return icon;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

    Bitmap b= eraseBG(result, -1); 
    // I then set my imageview to the bitmap!
    imageview.setImageBitmap(b);
    imageview.setVisibility(1);
}

// Rids the black from the image:
private static Bitmap eraseBG(Bitmap src, int color) {
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap b = src.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    b.setHasAlpha(true);

    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    src.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
        if (pixels[i] == color) {
            pixels[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    b.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    return b;
}
```

}

Im not entirely sure why its not working, the other class BitmapDecodeWhite is the same with the replacement of values for targeting white. I dont know if it matters but im laying multiple images on top of one another....

Help would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked how many pixels are replaced?

```
Bitmap b= eraseBG(result, -1);
[...]
if (pixels[i] == color) {
```

The color you want to replace does not have the value `-1`.

```
pixels[i] = 0;
```

Replacing it with `0` is probably counter-productive also as that is a fully transparent black.